# Cannot find service module info file '*/roslynRemoteHost.servicehub.service.json'

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

Visual studio crashes opening an existing or creating a new aspnet mvc application

[image]

Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
Version 15.8.1

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 10.0.14.393

The only valid entry in a google search was this one

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/27781

But no solution yet.

Event log Exception

```
    Application: devenv.exe
    Framework Version: v4.0.30319
    Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
    Message: StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Request locate failed with message: 
    Cannot find service module info file '*/roslynRemoteHost.servicehub.service.json' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\common7\ServiceHub\Services', using discovery services failed: VsixServiceDiscovery: One or more errors occurred.
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to debug the visual studio instance that was crashing with a new instance of visual studio I saw the following error.

> This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated
>   cryptographic algorithms.

Then I went to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`  and DELETED the `FipsAlgorithmPolicy`.

I did have the `DWORD Enabled = 0` under that subkey and it was not working. So again after deleting the subkey `FipsAlgorithmPolicy` I could open or create a web project again.

Comment: Is there any way to resolve this without reming the FIPS required setting? My company is forcing this setting on new computers and it really is messing things up.